# Solve the differential equation with the corresponding replacement

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

So I have this problem from the Elementary Differential Equations by Kells:

Solve this differential equation with the corresponding replacement:
$$
(st+1)t\cdot ds+(2st-1)s \cdot dt=0$$
with
$$z=st$$
So my question is whether am I doing something wrong since I did the exercise but I'm not getting the same result (which should be $(st-2)^3t=cs$).
What I did is to make the substitution, take the differentials of it ($dz=dx\cdot y+x\cdot dy$) and then to put it into the main equation, which leaves:
$$
(z+1)t ds + (2z-1)s dt = 0
$$
Having $dt=\frac{dz-ds\cdot t}{s}$,
$$
zt\cdot ds+t\cdot ds+(2zs-s)(\frac{dz}{s}-\frac{ds\cdot t}{s})=0
$$
which leads finally to:
$$
st+c=ln(st)
$$
What am I understanding wrong about the process?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Their answer is correct. Since you didn’t show your work, I cannot tell what you did wrong. You have to eliminate all the $t$’s once you’re working with $z$, $dz$, $s$, and $ds$. Also, it’s easier to solve for $s\,dt$ than to have the extra algebra with $s$ and $1/s$. I suggest you edit your question to include the work. I will offer the hint that you should expect to have to use partial fractions.

Comment: You see, that's what I did not do, eliminate all the t's. Cool, thanks for the help, will do it!